# How to exclude OPTIONS, HEAD and PATCH method from spring-data-rest entityController

Tags: spring, spring-data-rest, springfox

I am using spring-data-rest-webmvc:jar:2.5.3.RELEASE to write REST API and rendered the resources in springfox-data-rest-2.6.0. The swagger renders all methods resides in `RestEntityController`. I excluded some methods in repository level by using `@RestResource(exported = false)`. But swagger loads all other HTTP methods like OPTIONS, HEAD and PATCH which I am unable to exclude from `RepositoryRestResource`.

How to render my swagger with clean resource that include only my CRUD and search methods? Need to support this either in using spring-data-rest configuration or using springfox configuration.

Comment: Tough question. Could you give me a hint what your RestEntityController is?

Answer (score 5):

After delving into the springfox documentation and discarding some dead end ideas, I come up with two solutions that might solve your issue. Apply and mix them according to your needs.

**Hint #1 - Filter by using the `RequestHandlerSelectors`**

Tell springfox which method endpoints you would like to show in the swagger-ui. Therefore you can setup your `RequestHandlerSelector` to scan your whole application, a specific package or classes and methods that you have annotated with a shared annotion.

```
//Example for the method scan based on springfox's @ApiOperation annotation

@Bean
public Docket api() {    
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)          
      .select()                                       
      .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.withMethodAnnotation(ApiOperation.class)).paths(PathSelectors.any())
      .build();
}



// Within your dao or repository class
public interface QueuedMessageDao extends CrudRepository<QueuedMessage, Integer> {
    @ApiOperation(value = "This method finds all messages that are queued with the recipient's email address")
    List<QueuedMessage> findByRecipientEmail(String email); 
}
```

This will cut off a lot of spring-data-rest overhead from your swagger documentation. But you will still (surprisingly) see unwanted HTTP methods in your swagger-ui, like the `GET`, `HEAD` and `OPTIONS` methods for your technical `/<entity>/search` endpoint. I say technical, because these endpoints are intended to discover other endpoints only, they don't serve you with data from your entities.

**Hint #2 - Filter by using the `PathSelectors`**

In case you want to get rid of the technical `/<entity>/search` endpoints in swagger, you can exclude them using a regex that filters out all search endpoints but keeps the endpoints that are relevant for you. To still have a business endpoint for searches within your entities, you just need to set up an implicit GET endpoint.

```
//Example for the method scan based on springfox's @ApiOperation annotation

@Bean
public Docket api() {    
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)          
      .select()                                       
      .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.withMethodAnnotation(ApiOperation.class)).paths(PathSelectors.regex("^(?!(/.*(/search)$)).*$"))
      .build();
}

// Within your dao or repository class
public interface QueuedMessageDao extends CrudRepository<QueuedMessage, Integer> {

    @ApiOperation(value = "this generates a business search endpoint")
    List<QueuedMessage> findById(int id);

    @ApiOperation(value = "This method finds all messages that are queued with the recipient's email address")
    List<QueuedMessage> findByRecipientEmail(String email); 
}
```

Now you got rid of the search endpoint but still have a business search in your swagger documentation.
Hope this helps!

Comment: My application doesn't have @ApiOperation for any method. Then How Should i prevent this (HEAD, OPTIONS, PATCH) in Repository Entity Controller which is provided by spring boot by default.

Comment: you cannot touch your repository classes to introduce swagger annotations?

Comment: Can I disable like setHeader("POST, GET, PUT, DELETE") in Docket configuration. Is there any possible at the configuration level??

Comment: I tried to figure out another solution using the `DocumentationContentBuilder` and set the `requestHandlers()` to a filtered list of `RequestHandler` objects. After some investigation it seems to turn out that springfox's `EntityServiceProvider` already sets all `RequestHandler`s and there is no way to reset them to an own list. Without much development effort, I currently see the only possibility in using annotations to very precise tell springfox which endpoints you would like to show in your documentation and which not.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem as you, I just wanted to show CRUD operations to my clients through Swagger UI. After digging in Springfox documentation,I created my own Predicate to filter endpoints only for CRUD operations, checking the requested Method.

```
@Bean
public Docket api() { 
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)  
        .select()                                  
            .apis(customRequestHandlers())
            .build();
}

private Predicate<RequestHandler> customRequestHandlers() {     
    return new Predicate<RequestHandler>() {
        @Override
        public boolean apply(RequestHandler input) {
            Set<RequestMethod> methods = input.supportedMethods();
            return methods.contains(RequestMethod.GET)  
                || methods.contains(RequestMethod.POST)
                || methods.contains(RequestMethod.PUT)
                || methods.contains(RequestMethod.DELETE);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Thank you VERY much. I have trawled for HOURS trying to find a way of doing this. and your great answer sits here...but I found it. If I could, I would give you 100 up ticks.

Answer (score 1):

Create a customized interceptor:

```
public class MyInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter{    
        @Override
        public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
            //let's disable OPTIONS and HEAD
            if (request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("OPTIONS") || request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("HEAD")) {            
                response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN, "Unauthorized Request");
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Then add it to the config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
     @Override
        public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry){
            registry.addInterceptor(new MyInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/**");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Excluding specific HttpMethods with Springfox 2 is pretty simple with its ApiSelectorBuilder which accepts Guavas Predicates.

This snippet will exclude all methods from the api-docs and swagger-ui.html which are OPTIONS, HEAD or PATCH.

```
@Bean
public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(Predicates.not(requestHandler -> {
                // exclude all methods being OPTIONS, HEAD or PATCH
                final Set<RequestMethod> methods = requestHandler.getRequestMapping().getMethodsCondition().getMethods();
                return !Collections.disjoint(methods, Arrays.asList(RequestMethod.OPTIONS, RequestMethod.HEAD, RequestMethod.PATCH));
            }))
            .build();
}
```

This can easily expanded to additionally exclude the common /errors Controller.

```
@Bean
public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(Predicates
                    .and(
                            // exclude /errors
                            Predicates.not(requestHandler -> requestHandler.getRequestMapping().getPatternsCondition().getPatterns().contains("/error")),
                            // exclude all methods being OPTIONS, HEAD or PATCH
                            Predicates.not(requestHandler -> !Collections.disjoint(requestHandler.getRequestMapping().getMethodsCondition().getMethods(),
                                    Arrays.asList(RequestMethod.OPTIONS, RequestMethod.HEAD, RequestMethod.PATCH)))
                    )
            )
            .build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For spring data rest we can filter http method here:

```
    private Predicate<RequestHandler> httpRequestHandler() {

    return p -> p.supportedMethods().contains(RequestMethod.GET)
            || p.supportedMethods().contains(RequestMethod.POST);
   }


    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .groupName("test-api")
            .apiInfo(apiInfo())
            .select()
            .apis(httpRequestHandler())
            .paths(PathSelectors.any()).build()
            .securitySchemes(Arrays.asList(securityScheme()))
            .securityContexts(Arrays.asList(securityContext()));
    }
```